# Store and access objects "externally" in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a HandlerInteceptor:

```
public class RequestInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

@Autowired
private AddressService addressservice

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    String ip_address = request.getRemoteAddr();
    addressservice.storeIp_address(ip_address);
    return true;
}
}
```

Object:

```
public class IpAddress {
private String ip_address;

public String getIp_address() {
    return ip_address;
}

public IpAddress setIp_address(String ip_address) {
    this.ip_address = ip_address;
    return this;
}
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class AddressService {
private IpAddress ipAddress;

public void storeIpAddress(String ip_address){
    ipAddress.setIp_address(ip_address);
}

public void getIpAddress(){
    ipAddress.getIp_address();
}}
```

Now how is it possible to save the IP address in another object so I can access it the next time a request gets intercepted? I have tried using @Service etc but I always get nullpointer exceptions. I can't get my head around how Spring-Boot works. It seems like rocket science to me.

**UPDATE:**

```
@Service
public class AccessService {
    private Map<String, LocalDateTime> access = new HashMap<>();

    public Map getAccess() {
        return access;
    }

    public void addAccess(String ip_address, LocalDateTime date) {
        access.put(ip_address, date);
    }
}
```

Interceptor:

```
public class RequestInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

@Autowired
private AccessService accessService;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(accessService.getAccess().values());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
        LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.now();
        accessService.addAccess(request.getRemoteAddr(), datetime);
        System.out.println(accessService.getAccess());
    }
}
```

I still get Nullpointer Exceptions..

**UPDATE2**
I finally made it work:

```
    public class RequestInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    private Map<String, LocalDateTime> access = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        String ip_address = request.getRemoteAddr();
        for (String key : access.keySet()){
            if (access.get(key).plusSeconds(5).isBefore(LocalDateTime.now())){
                access.remove(key);
            }
        }
        if (access.containsKey(ip_address) == true){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
        access.put(request.getRemoteAddr(), LocalDateTime.now());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also share your service class??

Comment: Just did. Tried autowiring the AddressService class into the interceptor and then use the "storeIpAddress" method but that always got me nullpointer exceptions..

Comment: I can't really see where are you using your `@AddressService` Class??

Comment: Anything missing in your code?? I mean the `@Autowired` stuff..!!

Comment: Check again, sorry.

Comment: Please add stack trace to help finding the root cause..!!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by storing the object in session scope and get the value wherever you want.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("ip_address",ip_address);
```

and used it next time by using getAttribute().

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
 String ip_address = session.getAttribute("ip_address");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your service class, the object for `IpAddress` class is not initialized. So throwing null pointer at setter method.

I should have asked for stack trace too. My fault !! :P

Okies..!!

**Solution:**

```
@Service
public class AddressService {
private IpAddress ipAddress = new IpAddress();

public void storeIpAddress(String ip_address){
    ipAddress.setIp_address(ip_address);
}

public void getIpAddress(){
    ipAddress.getIp_address();
}}
```

**UPDATE**

One serious problem with this approach is, you would get the same object again and again, where as a POJO (like `IpAddress`) class must always be a new Object (unless needed).

Also, It looks like you are **OVER-USING** the service pattern.

I mean, it's just a String Object in your POJO class, so why are you making a POJO of it.

**POJO: Plain Old Java Object.

Comment: I'm trying to limit calls by an IP to 1 for every 5 seconds. My idea was to store the IP address and the time into a hashmap and check both every time a request gets intercepted (That's why I want to use the same object). Is that a stupid approach?

Comment: Hmm.. More opinionated question..!! My answer is, not so stupid..! Store in `Set<String>` instead. `Set` would contain only unique values, so no duplicate entry. also you can delete entry from set easily.

Comment: Why not just use a `HashMap<String, LocalDateTime>` and perform a lookup during your interception? You can then compare times and stuff. 

I also disagree that you're overusing the service pattern -- it's my opinion that your interceptor is basically acting like a controller that should perform business logic, and delegate all of the other work to your service (like you're doing). We could have endless discussions around these patterns, but you're doing it how I would (minus the POJO).

Comment: @XaeroDegreaz Great to go..!!